# Couldn't check out Watin Test Recorder using svn

Tags: c#, svn, watin

I tried to check out the Watin Test Recorder from http://sourceforge.net/p/watintestrecord/code/195/tree/version3/

And the svn link I tried was: svn://svn.code.sf.net/p/watintestrecord/code/trunk watintestrecord-code

Is there any problem with this url?

The error from svn is "Unknown host name 'svn.code.sf.net'

Thankss

Comment: This doesn't seem like a question best suited for StackOverflow - it's not programming, nor is it going to be useful to other people?  Have you tried the Watin support forums?

Comment: Try `svn checkout svn://svn.code.sourceforge.net/p/watintestrecord/code/trunk watintestrecord-code`

Comment: Thank for reminding me, but I believe that there could be a lot of people using Watin and could benefit from this post. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If you got "Unknown host name" - this is **local problem** of your **resolver**, doesn't related to svn in any form: `nslookup svn.code.sf.net`
2. URL *at least now* is **bad**

   z:>svn ls http://svn.code.sf.net/p/watintestrecord/code/trunk

   svn: warning: W160013: URL 'http://svn.code.sf.net/p/watintestrecord/code/trunk' non-existent in revision 195

and shortened URL haven't such problem

```
z:\>svn ls http://svn.code.sf.net/p/watintestrecord/code
version3/
```

Comment: By "resolver" you mean a DNS (e.g. some local one)?

Comment: @bahrep - do you want to get *here* big lecture abut DNS-basics? It's offtopic and useless here, from my POV. By resolver I mean "resolver", local DNS-client on host (part of OS), which interact with DNS-server(s) and provide answers for DNS-request to system

Comment: Nope, not here. Thank you for the short description :)

Comment: Brilliant, this what I'm looking for, I'm not so familiar with Svn yet :)